# Change Language in app ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating an app that requires to change the language at runtime
languages are: English, Chinese (Simplified) and Bahasa Malaysia and it doesn't kill the app

but the code I have kills the app

```
[[NSUserDefaults standard Userdefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zh-Hans", @"en", @"ms",nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

I want the app to just load the translations for Bahasa Malaysia and Chinese (Simplified) whenever their buttons are clicked not just the system language but within the app itself. with storyboards.

Comment: I highly suggest posting some example of effort/research/etc before others down-vote this question even further.

Comment: This question has been asked many times and the answer is YOU CAN'T.  You will need to implement this functionality yourself, independent of the system language and NSLocalizedString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
https://github.com/chenhaiteng/Localization-Utilities/tree/master/examples/LaunchWithLocale

It's an example shows how to launch apps with specified localization.

Comment: what if my project is with storyboards is this applicable?

Comment: If what you need is launching App with specified language, the example also works with storyboard. But if you need switch languages on the fly, there has no way to achieve it with storyboard now.

Comment: For programming purpose its ok. We cant force users to change main language ENG

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @ NSLocalizedString

See [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios) they are the basics of localising apps.

Also, in the future please provide as much info as possible.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: I want to change the language of the app

independently on the system language

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "independently on the the system language".

Comment: yes and when a user taps a button for example Chinese simplified Chinese Simplified text are automatically loaded and for Bahasa Malaysia button Malaysia texts will appear and it doesn't kill the app

Comment: NSLocalizedString is a tool, it depends how you use it. I personally (might not be the right way) but I would put everything in a JSON file and retrieve the language as necessary, updating the view with a localised string when the button is clicked